# "CognitoUserSession is not valid because idToken is null" Flutter

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter

anyone experienced this before? I am trying to call AWSMobileClient.getInstance().signIn(username, password, null, callback). But the callback is not being called. And it says that "CognitoUserSession is not valid because idToken is null"
It used to work on emulator before. But now it doesn't. But the same call works on Android devices

Comment: I have the same issue. I could not have found any response on google yet